# Positioning a div beneath other element on the page

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have an issue regarding the positioning of a div on my page. I would like to have it underneath my other two elements, but everything I have tried previously has not worked - even though the internet seemed to tell me that it should. 
Here is my code:

```css
#headingmain {
 position: relative;
 top: 150px;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 }
 #main {
 margin: 0 auto; 
 border-radius: 25px;
 background: #73AD21;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
  
 }
#para {
 position: relative;
 top: 150px;
 font-family: Comic Sans MS;
 }
 

 
#test {font-family: Comic Sans MS;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1 align="center" id="headingmain">Title</h1>
   <p id="para" align="center">para</p>

   <div id="main" align="center">
   <p id="test">Test</p>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

I cannot for the life of me find a tutorial on the internet that will position the div underneath the other two elements. This was my last resort, and I am thankful for any help you guys can provide.

Thanks again!

Comment: That's because you're using the Comic Sans font. Just kidding - what are you trying to do? Why should it be underneath the h1 and p tag? It is not there because you are using relative positioning on the previous elements. Remove it and everything will be fine. Something is telling me though that it won't look as you intend, that's why I am asking what is your desired result - there might be a better method to do it.

Comment: Thanks for that fix. My desired result was to have all of that lowered by around 150px. Any way to lower it all without screwing up the positioning?

And Comic Sans isn't that bad!

Comment: No problem. If you want to have everything lowered, you could also do position: relative; and top: 150px; on the remaining elements. Or you could just remove the position: relative; and top: 150px; from all elements as I suggested, and apply the following to the #headingmain - display:block; margin-top: 150px; However, it would be best to see at least the sketch or a design of the final result you're trying to achieve - maybe the answer by fbid is exactly what you need - using <div> elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple fiddle with the positioning you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/eh8ff325/3/

As you can see there are two nested div ( #one > #two ) and the #three div positioned below.

```
<main>
  <div id="one">One
    <div id="two">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="three">Three</div>
</main>
```

All the three div are inside a container which do the horizontal alignment and some top margin.

Comment: Thanks for this, makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark my answer as accepted if it worked, thanks.